# How can i check view performance issues after database migration?

Tags: sql, oracle

After migration few view's getting performance issue in production database.

My oracle Database migrated to AWSRDS database, but after migration few of view's getting performance issues in production database.

What i need to check in database side? Because existing database give fast result compare new database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Explain clause to check the performance of query in Oracle.

The general syntax is

```
         EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
             Query
```

Then fire the below query right after the 1st query is executed

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

You can read more about Explain [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#i17492)

Comment: @Shah. Before migration results it's gave very fastly. But after migration it's give performance issue. So i think need not check explain plan. Other than this any database checks like partition, table space. Please help me.

Comment: In that case you might need to identify performance issues in AWS RDS. In [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html), please refer to **Using Metrics to Identify Performance Issues**